# HTML encode asp.net tree view nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how to html encode nodes in a asp.net treeview control? I have a requirement that requires the nodes to have items that accepts "<" ">" symbols.

The code sample below is what I'm currently using as a treenode.

```
public class SampleTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    public SampleTreeNode(string text, string value)
        : base(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text), value)
    {

    }
}
```

The problem with this is that when I put it a node with text "". It displays the text as "<Test>" instead of "". I'm not sure if this is the best place to put the encode command.

Comment: Go through this link (especially the example code). `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HttpContex.Current.Server.HtmlEncode and HttpContex.Current.Server.HtmlDecode

Comment: Hmmn.. sorry but could you be more specific? I know the commands I'm just not sure where to put it in the code.

Comment: Can you please supply more details as well, maybe your aspx markup. Are you trying to include "<" ">" characters in node label? You know you can also use &gt; and &lt; characters which will render as "<" and ">"

Comment: By the way. i think i found where exactly to put it. so thanks! just a follow up question though. when i added the HtmlEncode command i ended up with  "&lt;TEST&gt;" would you know a way that i can display the text "<TEST>".

Comment: If i don't the text doesn't display at all. it seems it tries to read it as an html element?

Comment: just checked my code. i accidentally called HTML Encode twice. so sorry for that. it's working properly now. thanks!